# Using thor for complex command line tool

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface, thor

i want to create a command line tool in Ruby using Thor. This tool should be packaged as a gem so that it is easily installed and uninstalled.

Creating and publishing the gem, I have done. I also created several Thor scripts which also work. However, I do not know how to combine them.

My aim is to be able to call my tool the following way:
mytool task param --options
mytool taskgroup:task param --options

I know how to make one Thor script to be executable. However, how do I make a bunch of thor scripts accessible throw one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [relevant Gem documentation](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/20#default_executable), you could specify (in your .gemspec):

```
spec.executables = ['bin/foo', 'bin/bar']
spec.default_executable = 'bin/bar'
```

and have your gem install a bunch of executables (`foo` and `bar`). Or you write a wrapper for all your Thor scripts and specify:

```
spec.executables = ['bin/wrapper']
```

and have your gem install only one executable (`wrapper`).

Answer (score 0):

The teletype gem (https://github.com/piotrmurach/tty) does an amazing job at setting up all the scaffolding for this. Create your project with teletype and then just fill in the implementation.